# Get data from background script to content script before DOM processed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Data transfer ways between content script and background script all seems to be asynchronous and by the time they get a callback, the DOM has already been loaded/processed.

How could I possible have something loaded from chrome.storage or get data from background script
before DOM loaded?

Comment: [Injecting javascript variable before content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/45105934)

Comment: Also, in Firefox you can use [browser.contentScripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contentScripts) API for that.